# How to render charts which are stored in hidden div tags in amChart with angular 2 or 4

Tags: angularjs, typescript, charts, semantic-ui, amcharts

I happened to read the docs at AmChart and found that we have to use the method

> chart.invalidateSize()

but i'm new to angular and couldn't figure it out how. I tried creating an event and execute the method but rather the page crashed. It would be really helpful if someone can guide me in this. Thank you

Below is my typescript component to the charts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AmChartsService,AmChartsDirective} from "@amcharts/amcharts3-angular";
import {SuiCheckboxModule,SuiRatingModule} from 'ng2-semantic-ui';
import {IFeedbackform} from '../feedbackform'
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';
import {CourseidFilterPipe} from '../course-id-filter.pipe';
import {FeedbackformService} from '../services/feedbackform.service';
import {AccordionModule,AccordionGroup,AccordionHeading} from 'ngx-accordion';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-consolidatedtrainingfeedback',
  templateUrl: './consolidatedtrainingfeedback.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./consolidatedtrainingfeedback.component.css'],
     providers:[FeedbackformService]
})
export class ConsolidatedtrainingfeedbackComponent implements OnInit {
private chart:any;
private indextab:number=-1;
listFilter: string = '';
feed:IFeedbackform[];
  constructor(private AmCharts:AmChartsService,private feedbackService: FeedbackformService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.feed=this.feedbackService.getFeedbackform();
    this.chart=this.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
    {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": [
{
            "category": "Excellent",
            "column-1": 45
        },
        {
            "category": "Good",
            "column-1": 50,
        },
    {
            "category": "Average",
            "column-1": 21,
        },
    {
            "category": "Poor",
            "column-1": 10,
        },

  ],
  "titleField": "category",
  "valueField": "column-1",
  "labelRadius": 5,
  "radius": "20%",
  "legend":[
{
  "position":"right",
  "marginRight":100,
  "autoMargins":false
}
  ],
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]"
    } 

    );

     this.chart=this.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv1",
    {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": [
{
            "category": "Yes",
            "column-1": 40,
        },
        {
            "category": "No",
            "column-1": 4,
        },
    {
            "category": "Somewhat",
            "column-1": 17,
        },
  ],
  "titleField": "category",
  "valueField": "column-1",
  "labelRadius": 5,
  "radius": "20%",
  "legend":[
{
  "position":"right",
  "marginRight":100,
  "autoMargins":false
}
  ],
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]"
    }

    );

     this.chart=this.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv2",
    {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": [
{
            "category": "Definitely",
            "column-1": 0,
        },
        {
            "category": "Somewhat",
            "column-1": 2,
        },
    {
            "category": "Not at all",
            "column-1": 7,
        },

  ],
  "titleField": "category",
  "valueField": "column-1",
  "labelRadius": 5,
  "radius": "20%",
  "legend":[
{
  "position":"right",
  "marginRight":100,
  "autoMargins":false
}
  ],
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]"
    }

    );

     this.chart=this.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv3",
    {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": [
{
            "category": "Too Long",
            "column-1": 42,
        },
        {
            "category": "Adequate",
            "column-1": 50,
        },
    {
            "category": "Insufficient",
            "column-1": 7,
        },

  ],
  "titleField": "category",
  "valueField": "column-1",
  "labelRadius": 5,
  "radius": "20%",
  "legend":[
{
  "position":"right",
  "marginRight":100,
  "autoMargins":false
}
  ],
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]"
    }

    );

     this.chart=this.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv4",
    {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": [
{
            "category": "Excellent",
            "column-1": 34,
        },
        {
            "category": "Adequate",
            "column-1": 21,
        },
    {
            "category": "Not Adequate",
            "column-1": 3,
        },

  ],
  "titleField": "category",
  "valueField": "column-1",
  "labelRadius": 5,
  "radius": "20%",
  "legend":[
{
  "position":"right",
  "marginRight":100,
  "autoMargins":false
}
  ],
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]"
    }

    );
     this.chart=this.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv5",
    {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": [
{
            "category": "Excellent",
            "column-1": 50,
        },
        {
            "category": "Adequate",
            "column-1": 32,
        },
    {
            "category": "Not Adequate",
            "column-1": 17,
        },
    {
            "category": "Not Applicable",
            "column-1": 0,
        },

  ],
  "titleField": "category",
  "valueField": "column-1",
  "labelRadius": 5,
  "radius": "20%",
  "legend":[
{
  "position":"right",
  "marginRight":100,
  "autoMargins":false
}
  ],
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]"
    }

    );
     this.chart=this.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv6",
    {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": [
{
            "category": "Excellent",
            "column-1": 34,
        },
        {
            "category": "Adequate",
            "column-1": 21,
        },
    {
            "category": "Not Adequate",
            "column-1": 4,
        },
    {
            "category": "Not Applicable",
            "column-1": 2,
        },

  ],
  "titleField": "category",
  "valueField": "column-1",
  "labelRadius": 5,
  "radius": "20%",
  "legend":[
{
  "position":"right",
  "marginRight":100,
  "autoMargins":false
}
  ],
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]"
    }

    );
     this.chart=this.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv7",
    {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "none",
  "dataProvider": [
{
            "category": "Excellent",
            "column-1": 56,
        },
        {
            "category": "Adequate",
            "column-1": 32,
        },
    {
            "category": "Not Adequare",
            "column-1": 13,
        },
    {
            "category": "Not Applicable",
            "column-1": 10,
        },

  ],
  "titleField": "category",
  "valueField": "column-1",
  "labelRadius": 5,
  "radius": "20%",
  "legend":[
{
  "position":"right",
  "marginRight":100,
  "autoMargins":false
}
  ],
  "innerRadius": "60%",
  "labelText": "[[title]]"
    }

    );


  }

    onTabOpen(event):void{
      this.indextab=event.index;
    }

    onOpen()
    {
      this.chart.invalidateSize();
      console.log("okay");
    }


}
```

there are 6 charts in the code and below is my angular component code:

```
<div style="background-color:#ffffff">
<div class="ui icon input" style="background-color:#ffffff;width:100%">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]='listFilter'>
        <i class="search link icon"></i>
      </div>
</div>
    <div class="content" style="margin:1%;padding-right:3%">
      <div class="ui five column grid" style="padding-left:4%">
  <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        Course ID
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        Course
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
         Instructor
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        Start Date
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        End Date
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div height="100%">
    <div class="content" style="margin-top:1%;">
<div class="ui segment" *ngFor="let cou of feed | courseFilter:listFilter | paginate:{ itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }"style="width:100%;padding-left:3%">      
 <accordion>
 <accordion-group>
 <accordion-heading (click)="onOpen()">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="ui five column grid">
         <div class="column">{{cou.course_id}} </div> 
         <div class="column">{{cou.title | uppercase}} 
           </div><div class="column" style="padding-left:2%">{{cou.instructor}}</div>
         <div class="column"style="padding-left:3%">{{cou.from_date}}</div>  
         <div class="column"style="padding-left:4%">{{cou.to_date}} </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </accordion-heading>
    <div class="ui basic segment">
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="eight wide column" style="padding:4%">
      <div class="Header" style="font-size:40px;padding-top:1%">
Program Rating
    </div>
<div id="chartdiv" [style.width.%]="100" [style.height.px]="500"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="eight wide column" style="padding:4%">
      <div class="Header" style="font-size:40px;padding-top:1%">
  Objective
    </div>
 <div id="chartdiv1" [style.width.%]="100" [style.height.px]="500"></div>
  </div>
</div>  
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="eight wide column" style="padding:4%">
      <div class="Header" style="font-size:40px;padding-top:1%">
  Utility value
    </div>
<div id="chartdiv2" [style.width.%]="100" [style.height.px]="500"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="eight wide column" style="padding:4%">
      <div class="Header" style="font-size:40px;padding-top:1%">
  Duration
    </div>
 <div id="chartdiv3" [style.width.%]="100" [style.height.px]="500"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui basic segment">
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="eight wide column" style="padding:4%">
      <div class="Header" style="font-size:40px;padding-top:1%">
  Appropriateness
    </div>
<div id="chartdiv4" [style.width.%]="100" [style.height.px]="500"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="eight wide column" style="padding:4%">
      <div class="Header" style="font-size:40px;padding-top:1%">
  Understandable
    </div>
 <div id="chartdiv5" [style.width.%]="100" [style.height.px]="500"></div>
  </div>
</div>  
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="eight wide column" style="padding:4%">
      <div class="Header" style="font-size:40px;padding-top:1%">
  Sufficient Examples
    </div>
<div id="chartdiv6" [style.width.%]="100" [style.height.px]="500"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="eight wide column" style="padding:4%">
      <div class="Header" style="font-size:40px;padding-top:1%">
  Sufficient Exercises
    </div>
 <div id="chartdiv7" [style.width.%]="100" [style.height.px]="500"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</accordion-group>
 </accordion>
</div>
</div>

<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

I'm currently using AmCharts, AngularJS 2, Semantic UI and NGX-Semantic.

Comment: Are you intentionally starting the charts hidden?

Comment: Yes.. What I wanted to do was load all the charts needed and keep them hidden under different segments and when the user selects whichever segment they like the charts pop in.